# Physics material Friction works only in forward direction - used with wheel joint 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have created a car vehicle using 2D sprite, and connected circular wheel sprites to it using Wheel joint 2D. In controller script, When movement variable is non- zero i am creating instance of motor and enabling it.

```
if (movement == 0f) {

            backWheel.useMotor = false; 
        } else {

            backWheel.useMotor = true; 
            JointMotor2D motor = new JointMotor2D{ motorSpeed = movement, maxMotorTorque = backWheel.motor.maxMotorTorque }; 
            backWheel.motor = motor; 
        }
```

I am controlling direction by setting movement variable +ve or -ve. It is working perfectly in forward direction. However when i press left, on a moving car, it stops but than tire slips in backward direction , as if there were no friction. I have added physics material to both tire and ground, and behavior in forward direction is normal ( no slips).

is there friction only in one direction ? Or am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found what was wrong. Well, late night work has its pro and cons. cons mostly.

Anyhow, direction friction made no sense. In case you noticed I am applying motor to back wheel only. So when I was pressing brakes(changing direction) it was loosing touch with the ground. Thus slippery.

I could have never noticed this behavior in case I had applied motor to both wheels, but that wasn't required of my vehicle behaviour.

I solved the problem by adding more weight to back wheel, so that it was always in touch with the ground. Thus no slips.